# Add custom sensor to KSysGuard

Tags: kubuntu

I recently found out that it is possible to extend KSysGuard with Add-Ons via `File` - `Download New Tabs` to display additional information.

![Screenshot of KSysGuard showing CPU history, memory history, network transfer rates, core temperatures and hard disk transfer rates. This image is not rendered correctly because askubuntu.com does not allow uploading images with a new account.][https://i.imgur.com/zPpodNj.png]

I want to extend this view with a graph showing the power consumption measured by a smart plug. The smart plug is running a web server and I query the power consumption with a Python script. For simplicity, lets consider this placeholder script instead which prints a random integer between 0 and 2500 (inclusive).

```py
import random

power_consumption_watts = random.randint(0, 2500)

print(power_consumption_watts)
```

The next step would be to pipe this value to KSysGuard somehow, but I do not know how to do this. I found that the plugins created new files under `~/.local/share/ksysguard/*.sgrd` which might be relevant, but I do not understand how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. KSysGuard fetches the sensor values from the program `ksysguardd`, which unfortunately can not be extended easily, but it is possible to create a program with the same interface from which KSysGuard can read the new sensor data. Such a program needs to be able to process the following commands from standard input:

1. `monitors`, which lists all available sensors as `my_sensor_name\tinteger` or `my_sensor_name\tfloat` pairs,
2. `sensorname`, which prints the value of the sensor,
3. `sensorname?`, which prints the display name, min value, max value and unit of the sensor, again separated with tabs.

There should only be a single line break after each output. In addition, before each command, `ksysguard>`  without line break needs to be printed. Note the trailing space. Since KSysGuard is very finicky about the exact format, I added a Python script below which should be easy to extend to additional sensors.

### How to add additional sensors:

1. Create a function to fetch the sensor value from somewhere.
2. Create a new entry in the `sensors` dict. Fill in:

   1. The sensor name/key of the dict entry (**must not** include spaces!)
   2. The display name of the new sensor.
   3. The unit (MB, °C, kg, Watt, etc.)
   4. The data type (`float` or `integer`)
   5. The minimum value.
   6. The maximum value.
   7. The function to fetch the value.

### How to make the new sensors show up in KSysGuard:

1. Mark the Python script file as executable: `chmod +x fake_ksysguardd.py`
2. In KSysGuard, go to File - New Tab...
3. Enter title of new tab.
4. Click "OK".
5. Go to File - Monitor Remote Machine...
6. Enter anything for hostname.
7. Select "Custom command".
8. Enter the full absolute path of this file.
9. Click "OK".
10. New sensors should now show up in the Sensor Browser.
11. Drop the sensors from the sensor browser onto the "Drop Sensor Here" fields to see whether everything works correctly.

New tabs will usually be stored in `~/.local/share/ksysguard/MyNewTab.sgrd`

![Screenshot of detected sensors in KSysGuard. This image is not embedded correctly because askubuntu.com does not allow uploading images with a new account.][https://i.imgur.com/AYh6Eln.png]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

def get_sensor1_value():
    return random.random() * 1000

sensors = {
    "my_sensor1": {
        "display_name": "My Custom Sensor 1",
        "unit": "MB",
        "value_type": "float",
        "min_value": 0,
        "max_value": 1000,
        "get_value": get_sensor1_value,
    },
    "my_sensor2": {
        "display_name": "My Custom Sensor 2",
        "unit": "°C",
        "value_type": "integer",
        "min_value": -100,
        "max_value": 100,
        "get_value": lambda: random.randint(-100, 100),
    },
}

def process_command(command):
    # Print available sensors
    if command == "monitors":
        for sensor_name, sensor_info in sensors.items():
            value_type = sensor_info["value_type"]
            print(f"{sensor_name}\t{value_type}")
        return

    for sensor_name, sensor_info in sensors.items():
        # Fetch and print sensor value
        if command == sensor_name:
            get_value_func = sensor_info["get_value"]
            
            value = get_value_func()

            print(value)
            
            return

        # Print sensor name, range and unit
        if command == sensor_name + "?":
            display_name = sensor_info["display_name"]
            unit = sensor_info["unit"]
            min_value = sensor_info["min_value"]
            max_value = sensor_info["max_value"]
            
            print(f"{display_name}\t{min_value}\t{max_value}\t{unit}")
            
            return
    
    print("UNKNOWN COMMAND")

try:
    print("ksysguardd 1.2.0")

    while True:
        print("ksysguardd> ", end="", flush=True)

        # Wait for new command
        command = input()

        process_command(command)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
except EOFError:
    pass
```

If you prefer Perl, there is also [this nice script to display NVIDIA GPU information in KSysGuard](https://gist.github.com/Sporif/4ce63f7b6eea691bdbb18905a9589169)